# Some Ubuntu core Apps don’t start at random times until I reboot my system

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

I used to have a good old DELL Latitude E6510 with a HDD running Windows 7. I replaced it with Kubuntu 19.04 but realized that I preferred GNOME more, so I installed it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

For some time it seemed to work seamlessly, but eventually I ran into these problems:

- Nautilus doesn’t start unless I use Alt+F2 after using my computer for a considerable amount of time
- Gnome terminal doesn’t start in any way after using my computer for a considerable amount of time.
  Please don’t tell me to reinstall my system as I have a considerable amount of user data that I don’t wish to transfer.
  Note: I have been using SDDM instead of GDM as display manager is that the problem?

Comment: Why did you add that PPA?ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3  It was used when Ubuntu-GNOME was a flavor and not the default desktop (2017 & before) and support has now ended.  It doesn't have 'disco' support, so I'd suggest removing it & checking your `sudo apt update` messages, and I suspect you didn't use the commands you listed.

Comment: I followed the guide at https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-gnome-38-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I think I will try GDM3 now.

Comment: And as for how I used the PPA, I edited /etc/apt/sources.list to use the bionic release instead

Comment: 19.04 uses GTK+ libraries 3.32 and of course GNOME 3.32.  By adding gnome packages from 18.04 you are asking for older 3.28 libraries/programs. Did you confirm you won't get API/ABI breakage between those versions? as they can cause the issues you describe, which could make the system unreliable when you use certain functions or at certain times. If you want stability, don't mix releases unless you've done your homework & accessed the likely issues. I believe this is your issue, and I wouldn't trust your system without a lot of homework & viewing what 18.04/3.28 packages you have installed.

Comment: fyi: Using `sddm` won't make any difference, I use it too.  In my opinion it's related to API/ABI issues caused by mixing 3.28 apps/libs/toolkits & the expected 3.32 as expected in a Ubuntu 19.04 system. If I'm correct, the fix will be to (a) install all GTK+ 3.28 used packages & then use the intended 3.32 versions from 'disco' sources, or far quicker (b) re-install with something-else & no-format of partitions.  I  don't recall the release notes for gnome/GTK+ and thus don't recall the changes from 3.28 .. 3.30 .. 3.32 release and if significance, but this is where I'd bet your issue is.

Comment: My comments have got no upticks, so in your position I'd wait until other users of this site have seen your question and provided some input in the form of other causes, or provided some affirmation of my concerns [upticks]. If you did your homework on lib/toolkit changes between those releases you can ignore me completely (*as my thinking is generic without specific knowledge, I just know the amount of homework I'd want to do before I did what you did and thus would have avoided it, let alone when you need to move to 19.10, 20.04*)

Comment: Actually, I just finished installing the standard gnome from standard repos and it works

Comment: I would still check you don't have any packages installed from that PPA; remove them and PPA.  Yes the package versions should be higher in disco sources than the PPA (this case is more likely to be a compatible versioning thanks Jeremy Bicha, but you can't rely on that as there are many standards of versioning).

Comment: I have a bunch of GNOME dependencies and apps, but I removed them all and the PPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added a PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` which was used by Ubuntu GNOME when it was a Ubuntu flavor (main Ubuntu was using Unity 7) which was up to 17.04 (2017 & before). Its support has ended, plus there is no 'disco' support, so I'd suggest removing it & checking your sudo apt update messages.  I doubted you used your listed commands (*unaltered as they'd get errors*).

Ubuntu 19.04 uses GTK+ libraries 3.32 and of course GNOME 3.32. By adding gnome packages from 18.04, it expects older GTK+ 3.28 libraries/programs. Did you confirm you won't get API/ABI breakage between those versions? As they can cause the issues you describe, which could make the system unreliable when you use certain functions or at certain times.

If you want stability, don't mix releases unless you've done your homework & assessed the likely issues. I believed this was your issue, and I wouldn't trust your system without a lot of homework & viewing what 18.04/3.28 packages you have installed.

fyi: Using `sddm` won't make any difference, I use it too (on 18.04 & 19.10).

If I'm correct, the fix will be to either

- remove all GTK+ 3.28 used packages & then use the intended 3.32
  versions from 'disco' sources, or possibly quicker
- re-install something-else & no-format of partitions (*I see as safer in that it doesn't require you to audit looking for any leftover packages that'll create issues next release-upgrade*)

I don't recall the release notes for GNOME/GTK+ and thus don't know the changes from 3.28 .. 3.30 .. 3.32 releases and if significant changes, but this is where I'd bet your issue is. If you did your homework on lib/toolkit changes between those releases you can ignore me completely (*as my thinking is generic without specific knowledge, I just know the amount of homework I'd want to do before I did what you did and thus would have avoided it, let alone risking issues when you need to release-upgrade to 19.10, 20.04*)

[*This is my comments amalgamated, with a few bad typo/word corrections too.*]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question; thank you @guiverc in comments.
I was using a outdated GNOME version (3.11) from an old PPA.

Comment: Could you please explain how you solved it? That way, the next person with the same problem will find a solution.

Comment: @gsb Please note that guiverc won’t be noticed by addressing them in an answer. You should use comments for this. An answer should tell _how_ you solved your problem.